# Using deque to insert unsigned char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, deque

I want to push_back two dimensional char arrays into deque. The following did not work. How should defined m_message data variable in order push_back those data.

```
unsigned char message_data[2][1500]; //definition

func1(message_data[0]);
func1(message_data[1]);

std::deque<unsigned char*> m_messagedata;

m_messagedata.push_back(&message_data[0]);
m_messagedata.push_back(&message_data[1]);
```

Comment: You're pushing back pointers. Broken pointers.

Comment: `unsigned char message_data[0][1500];
unsigned char message_data[1][1500];`
is wrong : you declare two variables with the same name

Comment: `m_messagedata.push_back(message_data[0]);` - without &

Comment: In this case, I only push_back the pointers of the variables. What should I do in order make a complete copy inside the deque.

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing back pointers, not arrays. If those arrays die, your pointers dangle. You didn't tell us what your problem is, but this is likely to be it.

Also you seem to be declaring two arrays with the same name, with different bounds, one of which is illegal (0). I presume that this was a mistake with your question, rather than your original code: please post [your *real* testcase](http://sscce.org) next time.

Nowadays, C++ has a wrapper around what were previously uncopyable arrays, allowing them to be stored directly inside standard containers; that wrapper is called `std::array`. So, try:

```
#include <array>
#include <deque>

typedef std::array<unsigned char, 1500> ArrayType;

int main()
{
   std::array<ArrayType, 2> message_data;

   std::deque<ArrayType> q;
   q.push_back(message_data[0]);
   q.push_back(message_data[1]);
}
```

Note that the container now contains *copies* of the two inner arrays.

Comment: Sorry but is it possible to do it without std::array.

Comment: @AvbAvb: Why..? There's `boost::array` if you can't use C++11.

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions are right but since you want your code to remain the same as far as possible maybe you could do this:

```
unsigned char message_data[2][1500]; //definition
//using CharArrPtr = unsigned char(*)[1500];
typedef unsigned char (*CharArrPtr)[1500];
std::deque<CharArrPtr> m_messagedata;
m_messagedata.push_back(&message_data[0]);
m_messagedata.push_back(&message_data[1]);
```

As was mentioned earlier what is being done here is pushing pointers to possibly local variables. So you will have to be sure that they remain valid when they are used.

Comment: Sure, as long as the original array remains in scope. The OP did ask for copies of the data. Also you have a syntax error

Comment: I have upvoted you as your answer is close to what the OP expected though I am not sure why he wanted a different solution